# How to update Remote/Origin on another computer after branch renaming

Tags: git, git-branch

I found a way to update my computer and Remote/Origin branch to match when I rename a branch.

you can imagine renaming branch as:

```
git checkout oldBranchName

git branch -m renamedBranch

git push origin :oldBranchName renamedBranch // deletes old branch and push the renamed branch
```

My computer's local `.git/refs/remotes/origin` is updated and any use of CLI or GUI(for git like Sourcetree) looks correct on my computer.

I am trying to find an easy/least risky way of updating the reference on a coworker's computer.

Something like:

```
# !!! Fake git command, only for clarifying a point
git update --refs

OR

git pull/fetch --refs
```

- Using `--set-upstream` to link branch "oldBranchName" to origin/renamedBranchName is confusing.
- "git update-ref" seems dangerous and not really what I am looking for.

Note: I do understand that my coworker can delete the old branch and pull the new renamedBranch, however, this does not scale well to 10 coworkers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

This is a bit long, so here's a TL;DR simple recipe for each of them:

1. run `git fetch --prune`;
2. if they have a branch named `oldBranchName`, run:

   ```
   git branch -m oldBranchName renamedBranch
   git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/renamedBranch renamedBranch
   ```

   (in that order).  If they don't have that branch, these two commands will fail (harmlessly).

That's it: just the three commands (or one command if they have no `oldBranchName`).  The longer version below explains what this is for and gives an alternative sequence in the rare case that they have a really ancient Git version that lacks a few of these options.

## Long

They need to run `git fetch` to see the *new* branch name, which will show up in their clone as `origin/renamedBranch`.  They can run this command at any time (unlike `git pull`, which can only be run at "safe" times).  But there are two remaining issues:

1. They will *still have* `origin/oldBranchName`, at least by default (see more below).
2. If they have a branch named `oldBranchName`, they still have that branch, still named `oldBranchName`.  *There is nothing wrong with this as far as Git is concerned:* a branch name in *your* clone need not match the branch name in some *other* clone, including the clone over at `origin`.  But it's *confusing to work with*.

To fix item 1, they need to tell their own Git software to "prune" remote-tracking names (the various `origin/*` names) that no longer exist as *branch* names over on `origin`.  The key to understanding this is:

- Each repository has *its own* branch names.  Your branch names are *yours* and their branch names are *theirs*.  We (humans) like to use the *same name* to keep things simple, but that's not a Git requirement.
- Whenever they run `git fetch`—and remember that `git pull` is a convenience command that runs *two* Git commands *for you*, with the *first one* being `git fetch`; it's the *second* command that makes `git pull` hard—their Git software calls up some other Git software over at `origin`.  The Git software over at `origin` lists out all the branch names in the clone at `origin`.  So *their* Git (their software, operating in/on their repository) sees `origin`'s Git's branch names.  *Their* Git takes each of these names and *renames* it by sticking `origin/` in front of it.<sup>1</sup>  The result is a *remote-tracking name* (identified in part by the `origin/` in front, and in part because if you ask for colorized branch-name-listings, Git normally prints the remote-tracking names in red and the [local<sup>2</sup>] branch names in green).
- So, your Git's remote-tracking names—`origin/main`, `origin/develop`, and so on—are your Git's way of remembering some other Git's names.  That's it!

The normal update process, though, goes like this:

1. you run `git fetch origin` (or just `git fetch`, which does the same thing);
2. your Git (your software in your repo) calls up their Git at `origin`;
3. they list out their *branch* names;
4. your Git changes their *branch* names into your *remote-tracking* names, using the same renaming system every time;
5. for each name obtained this way, your Git creates or updates the remote-tracking name.

If a branch name gets *deleted* on the remote, there's no corresponding remote-tracking name in step 4, so there's *no update* in step 5.  If `origin` *had* a branch `xyzzy` yesterday and you ran `git fetch`, your Git created `origin/xyzzy` in *your* Git yesterday.  Today, they have *no* `xyzzy`, and your Git *doesn't update* your `origin/xyzzy`.  It doesn't *remove* it either.  You're left with a *stale* remote-tracking name.

To clear out all the stale names, you have two Git commands:

- `git remote prune origin`, or
- `git fetch --prune origin`.

These supposedly do exactly the same thing.  There was a range of Git versions (whose numbers I forget, back in the 1.7 or 1.8 days) where the code was a little broken and one of the two commands worked better than the other, so if you have a really old Git and one of the two commands isn't working right, try the other one.  But both are *supposed to:*

1. call up the Git over at `origin` and have it list out its branch names;
2. do the usual renaming to form remote-tracking names; and
3. *remove* from your own repository any remote-tracking name for which there's no longer a *branch* name over on `origin`.

Step 3 here is the pruning part.  Using `git fetch --prune` will *also* do the regular `git fetch` work, while `git remote origin prune` will only do the pruning work.

Having now gotten rid of `origin/renamedBranch` in your own local clone, you now have one remaining problem: your own branch named `oldBranchName` still exists, if it existed before, *and* it still records `origin/oldBranchName` as its *upstream* setting, if it did so before.  So we must rename the branch.  That's easy: `git branch -m` does the trick.  With *one* name:

```
git branch -m foo
```

Git renames the *current* branch so that its name is now `foo`.  That's not what we want, unless the current branch *is* `oldBranchName`, but:

```
git branch -m oldBranchName renamedBranch
```

will rename the branch named `oldBranchName` to `renamedBranch` *even if* `oldBranchName` *is* the *current branch*.  So that handles the first part.

To fix the *second* part—that the branch we just renamed might still have `origin/oldBranchName` set as its upstream—we just need to use `git branch --set-upstream-to`.<sup>3</sup>  This takes, after the equals sign, the *new* upstream, and then an optional branch name like `git branch -m`.  If you don't give the optional branch name, it updates the *current branch*—not what we want unless `oldBranchName` *is* the current branch—so again we provide the renamed branch name:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/renamedBranch renamedBranch
```

We've now:

- updated our `origin/*` names, clearing out the dead junk, via `git fetch --prune`; and
- renamed our local branch and fixed its upstream setting

and that is everything we need to do.

---

<sup>1</sup>Internally, Git does this with a crazy-complicated system, but that's the normal end result.

<sup>2</sup>The word *local* here is redundant: your branch names are *yours*.  They're *all* local.  Even your remote-tracking names are *local*, they're just *made up* from the remote's branch names.  They're made up freshly on *every* `git fetch`!

<sup>3</sup>If you have a very old `git branch` command, it may not have `--set-upstream-to`.  In this case it has `--set-upstream`, which takes its arguments in confusing order: `git branch --set-upstream renamedBranch origin/renamedBranch`.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put such a detailed explanation. I have not gone through all of it, however, from what I gather so far it addresses my current needs. Thank you again.